# How do I catch a handle a null value in a concatenated string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following in a view

```
c2.title + ' ' + c2.initials + ' ' + c2.surname AS referredTo
```

As it stands now, if one of those values are null, then referredTo is just null.  But for some of the records, the title, the initials, or the surname may be null.  What is the best way to handle this so that is one or more of the values are null, it will return only the string with the non-null values.  So for example, if title is null, it will only return "initals surname", if initials is null, it will return "title surname", if both are null, it will return "surname", etc, to cover any of those values being null.  This is probably a really easy answer but I'm kinda new to SQL and having to learn as I go.

Thanks.

Comment: [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

Comment: Rather `COALESCE()`, which is ANSI SQL.

Comment: Try `coalesce(...)`

Comment: so would that be something like ISNULL(c2.title, '')+' ' +ISNULL(c2.initials, '')+ISNULL(c2.surname, '')?  Would this not then leave unnecessary blank spaces if some values were null?

Comment: @ailinmcc666 No, You can use L/RTRIM

Comment: @Sami Why add the extra overhead of `RTRIM` AND `LTRIM`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, put the White Space within the `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Title + ' ', '') + ISNULL(Initials + ' ','') + ISNULL(Surname,'')
FROM YourTable;
```

That means that you don't end up with WhiteSpace at the front, or (possibly) two spaces between Title and Surname if Initials has a value of `NULL`.

Comment: I'll go with this one.  It deals with the problem, eliminates extra spaces in between too.  True, it does leave a whitespace at the end if surname is null, but that's not really a problem, whitespace at the end wouldn't be noticed.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use ISNULL, please check following statement

```
RTRIM(
    LTRIM(
      ISNULL(c2.title,    '') + ' ' +
      ISNULL(c2.initials, '') + ' ' +
      ISNULL(c2.surname,  '')
    )
) AS referredTo
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works nicely, but I went for Larnu's answer because surname isn't nullable in the DB (sorry, should've specified that), so a trailing whitespace at the end wouldn't be an issue, so Larnu's answer does the job I want more succinctly.  But I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @FinalAnswer= ISNULL(@Col1, '') + ' ' +ISNULL(@Col2, '')
```

Try above approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)

```
Select LTRIM(RTRIM(Concat(c2.title,' ',c2.initials,' ',c2.surname))) AS referredTo
 FROM yourTable
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff3b9/1)

Comment: That won't work. That would mean for something called "Mr John Smith" The return result would be "Mr".